# Averaging down a column of averaged data

Tags: python, csv, average, multiple-columns

I am writing a code in python for a project that has to accomplish a few things;
1) read in data from an xls file column by column
2) average each row of the columns in groups of three
3) then average the resulting columns

I have accomplished 1 and 2 but can't quite seem to get 3, I think a lot of the trouble I'm having stems from the fact that I am using float however I need the numbers to 6 decimal places. Any help and patience is appreciated, I'm very new to python

```
v = open("Pt_2_Test_Data.xls", 'wb') #created file to write output to
w = open("test2.xls")

count = 0

for row in w: #read in file
    for line in w:
        columns = line.split("\t") #split up into columns
        date = columns[0]
        time = columns[1]
        a = columns[2]
        b = columns[3]
        c = columns[4]
        d = columns[5]
        e = columns[6]
        f = columns[7]
        g = columns[8]
        h = columns[9]
        i = columns[10]
        j = columns[11]
        k = columns[12]
        l = columns[13]
        m = columns[14]
        n = columns[15]
        o = columns[16]
        p = columns[17]
        q = columns[18]
        r = columns[19]
        s = columns[20]
        t = columns[21]
        u = columns[22]
        LZA = columns[23]
        SZA = columns[24]
        LAM = columns[25]

        count += 1

        A = 0
        if count != 0:  # gets rid of column tiles
            filter1 = ((float(a) + float(b) + float(c))/3)
            filter1 = ("%.6f" %A)
            filter2 =  (float(d) + float(e) + float(f))/3
            filter2 = ("%.6f" %filter2)
            filter3 =  (float(g) + float(h) + float(i))/3
            filter3 = ("%.6f" %filter3)
            filter4 =  (float(j) + float(k) + float(l))/3
            filter4 = ("%.6f" %filter4)
            filter5 =  (float(m) + float(n) + float(o))/3
            filter5 = ("%.6f" %filter5)
            filter6 =  (float(p) + float(q) + float(r))/3
            filter6 = ("%.6f" %filter6)
            filter7 =  (float(s) + float(t) + float(u))/3
            filter7 = ("%.6f" %filter7)
            A = [filter1, filter2, filter3, filter4, filter5, filter6, filter7]
            A = ",".join(str(x) for x in A).join('[]')

            print A
            avg = [float(sum(col))/float(len(col)) for col in zip(*A)]
            print avg
```

I have also tried formatting the data like so:

```
            A = ('{0}    {1}    {2}     {3}    {4}    {5}    {6}    {7}    {8}'.format(date, time, float(filter1), float(filter2), float(filter3), float(filter4), float(filter5), float(filter6), float(filter7))+'\n') # average of triplets
            print A
```

thinking I could access the values of each column and preform the necessary math on them by calling them like you would when using a dictionary, however this was unsuccessful:it seemed it was recognizing the data either as a row (so trying to access any column by [0] was out of bounds) or by the individual characters, not as a list of numbers. Is this related to using the float function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand which columns you want to average in 3), but maybe this does what you want:

```
with open("test2.xls") as w:
    w.next()  # skip over header row
    for row in w:
        (date, time, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t,
         u, LZA, SZA, LAM) = row.split("\t")  # split columns into fields

        A = [(float(a) + float(b) + float(c))/3,
             (float(d) + float(e) + float(f))/3,
             (float(g) + float(h) + float(i))/3,
             (float(j) + float(k) + float(l))/3,
             (float(m) + float(n) + float(o))/3,
             (float(p) + float(q) + float(r))/3,
             (float(s) + float(t) + float(u))/3]
        print ('['+ ', '.join(['{:.6f}']*len(A)) + ']').format(*A)
        avg = sum(A)/len(A)
        print avg
```

You could do the same thing a little more concisely with code like the following:

```
avg = lambda nums: sum(nums)/float(len(nums))

with open("test2.xls") as w:
    w.next()  # skip over header row
    for row in w:
        cols = row.split("\t")  # split into columns
        # then split that into fields
        date, time, values, LZA, SZA, LAM = (cols[0], cols[1],
                                             map(float, cols[2:23]), 
                                             cols[23], cols[24], cols[25])
        A = [avg(values[i:i+3]) for i in xrange(0, 21, 3)]
        print ('['+ ', '.join(['{:.6f}']*len(A)) + ']').format(*A)
        print avg(A)
```

Comment: yes! this looks like it will accomplish exactly what I want! However i am getting an error on the line "print ('['+ ', '.join(['{:.6f}']*len(A)) + ']').format(*A)" could you explain the significance of this part of the code "print ('['+ ', '.join(['{:.6f}']*len(A)) + ']').format(*A)" ? -Thank you

Comment: It's just a fancy way of creating the format string `'[{:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}]'` and then applying it to all the `float` values in list `A`. What error are you getting on the line?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Try `print ('['+ ', '.join(['{:.6f}']*len(A)) + ']')` and see if the output matches what's in my previous comment (without the surrounding single quotes).

Comment: I get 5 iterations of [{:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}], shouldn't I only be getting one?

Comment: Hmmm, that looks correct assuming those are multiple lines of output. Try `print ('['+ (', '.join(['{:.6f}']*len(A))) + ']').format(*A)` and if it still doesn't work just use `print '[{:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}]'.format(*A)`.

Comment: Since the `print` is inside the loop, it will print something each iteration (i.e. for each row of file except the header row).

Comment: If you're still getting an error, update your answer and put the whole Traceback into it formatted as code.

Comment: Please consider also up-voting my answer(s) if you feel they are worthy - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `decimal` module to display the exact numbers.

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 6 # sets the precision to 6
```

note that floating points are used which means that:

```
print(Decimal(1)/(Decimal(7)) # 0.142857
print(Decimal(100)/(Decimal(7)) # results in 14.2857
```

This means you probably need to set the precision to a higher value to get 6 decimal places...
for example:

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 28
print("{0:.6f}".format(Decimal(100) / Decimal(7))) # 14.285714
```

To give a complete answer to your question, could you explain what average you are looking for? The average over all (21) columns? Could you maybe post some test_data.xls?

Comment: ah, thank you, I did not know about the decimal module. This has the potential to be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using numpy.  I'm not sure how to read in xls files, but there seem to be packages out there that provide this functionality.  I'd do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

with open("test2.txt") as f:
    for row in f:
        # row is a string, split on tabs, but ignore the values that
        # don't go into the average.  If you need to keep those you 
        # might want to look into genfromtxt and defining special datatypes
        data = (np.array(row.split('\t')[2:23])).astype(np.float)
        # split the data array into 7 separate arrays (3 columns each) and average on those
        avg = np.mean(np.array_split(data,7))
        print avg
```

I'm not sure if the avg above is exactly what you want.  You might need to save off the smaller arrays (`smallArrays = np.array_split(data,7)`) then iterate over those, calculating the average as you go.

Even if this isn't exactly what you want, I recommend looking into numpy.  I've found it to be really easy to use and very helpful when it comes to doing calculations like you're trying to do.