# Separating rows of output by commas and staying in float

Tags: python, format, rows

I'm having a problem because I have an output of A formatted like so:

```
[0.018801, 0.011839, -3332.980568, 0.009446, -3332.984916, 0.007438, -3332.982958]
[0.020493, 0.015735, -3332.980353, 0.013179, -3332.968465, 0.055135, 0.135461]
[0.020678, 0.018212, -3332.983603, 0.011993, 0.097811, 0.014364, 0.099570]
[0.020758, 0.015798, -3332.982745, 0.013539, 0.086793, 0.007399, -3332.984997]
[-3332.992594, 0.014576, -3332.979745, 0.015103, 0.089420, 0.009226, 0.090133]
```

however, I need each row to be separated by a comma in order for it to work in this bit of code:

```
def mean(a):
    return sum(a) / len(a)
a = [A]
print map(mean, zip(*a))
```

is there any way to achieve this while still keeping A as a list of floats? because `', '.join` requires string values which will not allow me to take the mean

below is the code I am using to generate A:

```
with open("test2.xls") as w:
    w.next()  # skip over header row
    for row in w:
        (date, time, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t,
         u, LZA, SZA, LAM) = row.split("\t")  # split columns into fields

        A = [(float(a) + float(b) + float(c))/3,
             (float(d) + float(e) + float(f))/3,
             (float(g) + float(h) + float(i))/3,
             (float(j) + float(k) + float(l))/3,
             (float(m) + float(n) + float(o))/3,
             (float(p) + float(q) + float(r))/3,
             (float(s) + float(t) + float(u))/3]
```

Any help is appreciated

clarification:

I don't need a longer list necessarily I need the list I have to be the same but for each row to be separated by commas. so when I pass this through mean:

```
def mean(a):
    return sum(a) / len(a)
a = [A]
print map(mean, zip(*a)
```

I only get the last row:

```
[-3332.992594, 0.014576, -3332.979745, 0.015103, 0.089420, 0.009226, 0.090133]
```

However if I write the output of A and separate each row by a comma like so:

```
def mean(a):
    return sum(a) / len(a)
a = [[0.018801, 0.011839, -3332.980568, 0.009446, -3332.984916, 0.007438, -3332.982958],
[0.020493, 0.015735, -3332.980353, 0.013179, -3332.968465, 0.055135, 0.135461],
[0.020678, 0.018212, -3332.983603, 0.011993, 0.097811, 0.014364, 0.099570],
[0.020758, 0.015798, -3332.982745, 0.013539, 0.086793, 0.007399, -3332.984997],
[-3332.992594, 0.014576, -3332.979745, 0.015103, 0.089420, 0.009226, 0.090133]]
print map(mean, zip(*a))
```

I get the desired output of

```
[-666.582372, 0.015232, -3332.981403, 0.012652, -1333.1358714, 0.018713, -1333.128558]
```

or the mean of each column.
How can I do this without having to manually doctor the A vector with commas?

Comment: Sorry, what? Did you mean to build a larger list? Why not use `largerlist = []` and in your loop do `largerlist.append(A)`?

Comment: I really have *no* idea what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to generate a list of lists. However, you aren't saving each list -- every time you go through the loop you create a new record and then replace it with the next record. This is why a eventually just contains the last record.

The commas aren't relevant -- that's just Python's syntax. The values are not stored with commas internally!

Instead of assigning each record to A, initialize A as an empty list and then add each new record to the end.

```
A = []
with open("test2.xls") as w:
    w.next()  # skip over header row
    for row in w:
        (date, time, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t,
         u, LZA, SZA, LAM) = row.split("\t")  # split columns into fields

        A.append([(float(a) + float(b) + float(c))/3,
         (float(d) + float(e) + float(f))/3,
         (float(g) + float(h) + float(i))/3,
         (float(j) + float(k) + float(l))/3,
         (float(m) + float(n) + float(o))/3,
         (float(p) + float(q) + float(r))/3,
         (float(s) + float(t) + float(u))/3])
```

Answer (score 2):

Extrapolating from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489218/averaging-down-a-column-of-averaged-averages), I think you could do what you want with something like this:

```
def mean(a):
    return sum(a) / len(a)

averages = []
with open("test2.xls") as w:
    w.next()  # skip over header row
    for row in w:
        (date, time, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t,
         u, LZA, SZA, LAM) = row.split("\t")  # split columns into fields

        A = [(float(a) + float(b) + float(c))/3,
             (float(d) + float(e) + float(f))/3,
             (float(g) + float(h) + float(i))/3,
             (float(j) + float(k) + float(l))/3,
             (float(m) + float(n) + float(o))/3,
             (float(p) + float(q) + float(r))/3,
             (float(s) + float(t) + float(u))/3]
        averages.append(A)

print map(mean, zip(*averages))
```

Alternatively it could be done a little more concisely with code similar to this:

```
def mean(a):
    return sum(a) / len(a)

averages = []
with open("test2.xls") as w:
    w.next()  # skip over header row
    for row in w:
        (date, time, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t,
         u, LZA, SZA, LAM) = row.split("\t")  # split columns into fields

        A = [mean(map(float, (a, b, c))),
             mean(map(float, (d, e, f))),
             mean(map(float, (g, h, i))),
             mean(map(float, (j, k, l))),
             mean(map(float, (m, n, o))),
             mean(map(float, (p, q, r))),
             mean(map(float, (s, t, u)))]
        averages.append(A)

print map(mean, zip(*averages))
```

And even more concisely with this:

```
def mean(a):
    return sum(a) / len(a)

averages = []
with open("test2.xls") as w:
    w.next()  # skip over header row
    for row in w:
        cols = row.split("\t")  # split into columns
        # then split that into fields
        date, time, values, LZA, SZA, LAM = (cols[0], cols[1], cols[2:23],
                                             cols[23], cols[24], cols[25])
        A = [mean(map(float, values[i:i+3])) for i in xrange(0, 21, 3)]
        averages.append(A)

print map(mean, zip(*averages))
```

In the last one you could rename `averages` to `a` if you wanted because there is no longer a field named `a` that would conflict with it. Regardless, all code fragments will print the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the list of floats into a list of strings using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
','.join(str(f) for f in A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str()` to convert them to string before passing them to `str.join`, this won't affect the original items at all:

```
>>> lis = [0.018801, 0.011839, -3332.980568, 0.009446, -3332.984916, 0.007438, -3332.982958]
>>> print ", ".join(str(x) for x in lis)
0.018801, 0.011839, -3332.980568, 0.009446, -3332.984916, 0.007438, -3332.982958
```

List still contains floats:

```
>>> lis
[0.018801, 0.011839, -3332.980568, 0.009446, -3332.984916, 0.007438, -3332.982958]
```